# Python default params confusion

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and I'm confused about this example:

```
def append_to(element, to=None):
    if to is None:
        to = []
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

If `to` was initialized once, wouldn't `to` not be `None` the 2nd time it's called?  I know the code above works but can't wrap my head around this "initialized once" description.

Comment: In this bad example (I call it bad because if you pass a `str` this thing goes wreck...) anyway, here either `to` is `None` or is a list. You won't create a list if `to` is not `None`. Therefore, you only assign a value to `to` under a call of this fashion:  `append_to('dreamfly')` whilst in this case: `append_to('dreamfly', users)` where `users` would be a list, you create no list inside the function, you just append the value (`users = [..., 'dreamfly']`).

Comment: That's an example from http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: I gave some [feedback](https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-guide/issues/813); the example uses non-mutable objects as default arguments which is a good thing but the missing validation can break other parts of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If "to" was initialized once, wouldn't "to" won't be "None" the 2nd time it's called?

`to` would become `None` if you don't pass a value for it: `append_to(1)` and only when `to` is `None` will your code rebind the local name `to` to a newly created list inside the body of your function: `to = []`.

The default values of functions are assigned only *once*, that's whatever you assign as a default value, that object will be used for every call you make to the function and will not change, typically the same reference of the default value will be used for every call you make to the function. This matters when you assign mutables as defaults:

```
l = [] 
def defArgs(d=l)            # default arguments, same default list for every call
    d.append(1)
    return d 

defArgs() is l            # Object identity test: True
```

Run the above function multiple times and you will observe the list growing with more elements because you get only one single copy of argument defaults for every function shared by every function call. But notice here:

```
def localVars(d=None):
    if d is None: 
        d = []               # Different list for every call when d is None
```

`d = []` is executed every time you call `localVars`; when the function finishes its job, every local variable is garbage-collected when reference count drops to 0, *but not the default values of arguments, they live after the execution of the function and are not typically garbage-collected after the execution of the function*.

Comment: I think I got what you mean after reading a few times.  The key here is not the scope of the variable but rather the object used to initialize the variable.  When they say "initialized once" they meant initialized the object where the parameter is pointing to once and link that object to the parameter every time the function is called. So if the object is immutable, it can never be changed.  If it's mutable, it will retain the last value.  Now it's all clear.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd rather use the term *assignment* instead of initialization here for precision. And yes you're right, if an object is immutable, you cannot change it. Unlike mutables where you can change *part* of the object `d[0] = 20`, here you really just changed part of `d`, the index 0. You cannot change part of ints or tuples for example, because they're immutables: `a = 20` and then you rebind `a` to 30: `a = 30` now `a` has a different reference referring to 30 and `a` is not the same as the previous `a`. Hope this makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def append_to(element, to=None):
    to = ...
```

`to` here becomes a *local variable* and is assigned to a list, and is deallocated if you don't assign return value to another variable.

If you want `to` staying alive for subsequent calls to `append_to` you should do:

```
def append_to(element, to=[]):
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lst = append_to(5)
>>> append_to(6)
>>> append_to(7)
>>> print lst
[5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: in your "to=[]" example, wouldn't "to" is also a local variable and whatever it's pointing to which is "[]" will be garbage collected since "to" will be gone also after the function exited?

Comment: No it is not a local variable and it won't be gone even after `append_to` is called because it's bound to function. You keep calling `append_to`, same `to` value is added new elements.

Comment: So what makes the "to=None" a local variable and "to=[]" not a local variable?  Is it dependent on the mutability of the value?  That may be how I can mentally remember it even though it's still a little bit illogical to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is no declaration and initialization stage when you use a variable. Instead, all assignment is a definition where you bind an instance to the variable name.

The interpreter bind the instance to the default value when instantiate the function. When the default value is a mutable object and you only change its state by its methods than the value will be "shared" between calls.